# SqlPackage does not deploy referenced DAC package

Tags: deployment, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac, sqlpackage, dac

I have created a solution with two database projects: *Dependent.sqlproj* and *Dependency.sqlproj*. The *Dependent.sqlproj* references to *Dependency.sqlproj*:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <SqlCmdVariable Include="Dependency">
    <DefaultValue>Dependency</DefaultValue>
    <Value>$(SqlCmdVar__4)</Value>
  </SqlCmdVariable>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Dependency\Dependency.sqlproj">
    <Name>Dependency</Name>
    <Project>{d635d16a-0d11-4c0a-b4c3-a646e442d8f4}</Project>
    <Private>True</Private>
    <SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>False</SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>
    <DatabaseSqlCmdVariable>Dependency</DatabaseSqlCmdVariable>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

After compitation of *Dependent.sqlproj* the *bin* folder looks fine, because it contains following files:

- Dependency.dacpac
- Dependency.dll
- Dependency.pdb
- Dependent.dacpac
- Dependent.dll
- Dependent.pdb

But despite all my efforts the following command creates *only* `Dependent` database on a target server:

```
sqlpackage /a:Publish ^
  /sf:Dependent.dacpac ^
  /tsn:"(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" ^
  /tdn:Dependent ^
  /dsp:Deployment.sql ^
  /df:Deployment.log ^
  /p:IncludeCompositeObjects=true ^
  /v:Dependency=Dependency
```

Note, the *Deployment.log* proves the package dependency is resolved:

> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.Tracer Information: 0 : 2021-09-12T21:33:17 : Searching for file DEPENDENCY.DACPAC using relative path ****\Dependent\bin\Debug
> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.Tracer Information: 0 : 2021-09-12T21:33:17 : Searching for file DEPENDENCY.DACPAC in directory ****\Dependent\bin\Debug
> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.Tracer Information: 0 : 2021-09-12T21:33:17 : Resolved file DEPENDENCY.DACPAC using path ****\Dependent\bin\Debug\Dependency.dacpac

But *Deployment.sql* contains nothing about `Dependency` database. So, what do I do wrong?

I understand, it's possible to deploy all packages successively, but it seems the [`IncludeCompositeObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacdeployoptions.includecompositeobjects?view=sql-dacfx-150) parameter should do it automatically. If not, what is the point of the parameter?

**Environment**

SqlPackage version is 15.0.5176.1.
SQL Server version is 13.0.4001.

Comment: as far as I know that you can deploy 1 database at a time, so you should deploy `Dependency` first and then deploy `Dependent`

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev, yes, it's possible. But it seems to me, the [IncludeCompositeObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacdeployoptions.includecompositeobjects) parameter should make it unnecessary to reinvent the wheel. What's benefit of the parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure, however I'm just wondering what to do with variables in such case? Extend then in single publish profile? Need to test that